# Сессия opencart 2.0

Tags: opencart

Здравствуйте. Задача такая храню информации в сессии таким образом:

```
$this->session->data['cartitem']
```

но как закрываю браузер сессия удаляется, как избежать удаления именно этой сессии?

Comment: пример : на 2 минуты  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',time()+120);

Comment: в opnecart сессия может хранится даже вечно, пока браузер не закроют.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы увеличить жизнь сессии необходимо сделать следующее:

Открываем файл **/system/library/session.php**

Ищем:

session_set_cookie_params(0, ‘/’);
и заменяем на

session_set_cookie_params(sec, ‘/’);

Или напрямую в вашем коде моте вызвать эту функцию

```
 session_set_cookie_params(sec, ‘/’);
```

sec — это время жизни сессии в секундах.

Или пользоваться [PHP функцией ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',600);](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)

Comment: Ну как бы не хочется трогать ядро движка, нет ли других способов, корзина ведь как то хранит долго товары в сессию

Comment: @newprogrammer ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',time()+120); пробовали ?

Comment: а зачем? я ведь сказал что теряю сессию при закрытии браузера

Comment: @newprogrammer Кстати можно и напрямую вызвать функцию session_set_cookie_params(120, ‘/’);

Comment: Эти ограничении зависит от сервера что ли почему `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',time()+120);`

Comment: @newprogrammer  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',600); http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57962/discussion-between-vanya-avchyan-and-newprogrammer).

Answer (score 2):

Помогли эти строчки:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',time()+10080);
session_set_cookie_params(time()+10080, '/');
```

нужно прописать оба в `/system/library/session.php`